# Does an entangled electron retain its entangled state if introduced into a metal?

Tags: electrons, quantum-entanglement

If an experiment is performed where a pair of entangled electrons is generated, and then one of the pair is introduced into a metallic body, for the sake of argument say a one centimeter cube of copper, such that it becomes part of the "electron cloud" within that metal where the copper atoms are held together with metallic bonds, does that electron retain its entangled state with the entangled electron outside of the metal? - or does becoming part of the electron cloud of the metallic body and the ensuing interactions cause a collapse of its wave function?

Further, if the metal is heated, and the entangled electron within the metal is emitted from the metal (along with countless others) via thermionic emission into a surrounding vacuum, does it still remain in its entangled condition, or does participation of the electron in thermionic emission collapse the wave function?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Entanglement is correlating the momentum, speed, direction,etc. of the two particles. When you change anything about one of the particles then the two are no longer correlated.

Comment: @BillAlsept That's not correct. Changing a property of one of the particles doesn't undo the entanglement. As an example, consider the entangled state $|0\rangle|0\rangle+|1\rangle|1\rangle$. Apply the unitary transformation $|0\rangle\leftrightarrow|1\rangle$ to the second particle. Then the new state is $|0\rangle|1\rangle+|1\rangle|0\rangle$. Still entangled. We can't undo the entanglement of two particles by applying a unitary transformation to only one of them.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly The math doesn’t even attempt to explain what’s physically happening. The OP is asking if one of the electrons is physically affected by the metal what would happen. Well, physically their trajectories would be different after that and no longer correlated. You have to remember both of the electrons are physically (really) doing something. The math makes you lose focus of that. You cannot physically describe what entanglement is other than correlating them.

Comment: @BillAlsept You're right that the math that I showed in the comment doesn't attempt to explain what's physically happening. It was not meant to be an answer to the OP's question. It was only a counterexample to the assertion in your first comment, assuming that we're talking about quantum theory. If your assertion is based on a different theory, then maybe you could clarify what theory you had in mind. Nobody is omniscient, so aside from a rote list of experimental data, we can't talk about what is "physically happening" without assuming some kind of theory.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly my assertion is physically based because the question included a physical interaction of one of the particles. My assertion is not a theory because we know the electrons are REALLY doing something physical. Physically the two particals were correlated but after the interation they were not.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly of course no one is omniscient but I'm not the one basing my argument on an incomplete theory. I like to follow the physics and everyone knows when two particles are correlated. How do you know when two particles are entangled?

Comment: If an unentangled electron were introduced into the metal where the electron is initially in a spin up or down state, and where the metal is not in the presence of an external electric or magnetic field, would interactions of that electron with other electrons and atoms inside the metal change its spin?  Would the answer change depending on the temperature of the metal, including the possibility of near absolute zero?  If not, then how would introduction of the entangled electron into the metal object cause its initial spin up/down superposition to collapse to either spin up or spin down?

Comment: @Roger let’s say you decide to entangle two electrons and then you actually do it. How do you know when the two real electrons are entangled and not just correlated? You had to physically do something to get them to be entangled. What is it that you did, that was not correlation??

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly:  As you might or might not be aware, Bill Alsept is going to say the things he wants to say about quantum entanglement no matter how many times and in how many ways people explain to him that those things are entirely incorrect.  There is no point in arguing, but I believe it's useful to mention this in comments now and then just to warn newcomers that Bill's comments about quantum entanglement are always and everywhere wrong.

Comment: @Roger Defining that question is tricky, because the standard theory doesn't have observables tied to individual electrons. When two electrons are well-separated in space, we can use location in space to define which electron we're talking about, and then statements like "their spins are entangled with each other" have the standard meaning. But if you put one of the electrons into a metal, then we no longer have any good way to define what "this individual electron" means, because electrons in a metal are not that well-localized.

Comment: @Roger An electron outside the metal may still be identifiable by its separate location, though, so asking whether that electron is entangled with the metal (as a whole) is still within the scope of the standard meaning of "entangled."

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Thanks. Re your comment: "But if you put one of the electrons into a metal, then we no longer have any good way to define what "this individual electron" means, because electrons in a metal are not that well-localized." - is this a limitation of the physics where the wave function of a single electron in an electron cloud within a metal is spread out, or is the statement "we no longer have any good way to define what 'this individual electron' means" a statement about the limitation of our current understanding and/or method of analysis, or both?

Comment: @WillO What do you mean there’s no sense in arguing?? You never do have an argument , you only complain. How do you know when two particles are entangled and not just correlated? You can’t answer that That’s why you never argue.

Comment: @Roger It's because electrons are "identical" fermions. That language is traditional, but it doesn't really convey the important concept. The important concept is that the theory doesn't have any observables tied to individual electrons. It only has observables tied to regions of space. That's not a limitation of the theory/understanding. It's a important feature of the theory/understanding. It's where the Pauli exclusion principle comes from, among other things. Classical physics doesn't have any analog of this, but it's absolutely central to understanding the quantum physics of electrons.

Answer (score 1):

Of course a unitary transformation on one half of your entangled system can't disentangle it, so I'll assume that whatever you're doing to your electron is non-unitary, and hence equivalent to some observation.  Let $A_1,\ldots A_n$ be the eigenstates of that observation, which we can take to ve a basis for the electron's state space, with $v_1\ldots v_n$ the corresponding eigenvalues.

Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ be a basis for the state space of the other electron.  (I am taking the state spaces to be finite dimensional for simplicity.)

Suppose your entangled pair is initially in the state
$$S=\Sigma_{i,j}\alpha_{ij}A_i\otimes X_j$$

Write

$$T_i=\Sigma_j\alpha_{ij}A_i\otimes X_j$$
so that $S=\Sigma_iT_i$.

Let $v$ be the outcome of your observation.  Then the new state of the pair is (proportional to)
$$\Sigma_{v_i=v}T_i$$
which (clearly) is entangled if and only if there is more than one $i$ with $v_i=v$ and $T_i\neq 0$.